# Counting records by sql query and saving the all counts in one data extensions in different columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, data, sql

So, I have two data extensions and I want to calculate count in 3rd data extension in each individual column.

My DE 1 (included all Emails of customers)
My DE 2 (included all Emails and Status of customers)

---

### DE 1

Email

---

### DE 2

Email &
Status

(Status column can have values like: Enabled, Disabled, OnHold and so on...there is a long list)

In my final 3rd DE, I am trying to do this with columns:

---

### DE 3

Enabled_Count, Disabled_Count, OnHold_Count

(all fields are NULLABLE for testing purpose)

I want to calculate all counts in different columns and this is what I am trying:

```
SELECT Count(CASE WHEN c.Email IN (Select distinct Email from DE2 WHERE Status = 'Enabled') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Enabled_Count,
Count(CASE WHEN c.Email IN (Select distinct Email from DE2 WHERE Status = 'Disabled') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Disabled_Count,
Count(CASE WHEN c.Email IN (Select distinct Email from DE2 WHERE Status = 'OnHold') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OnHold_Count
FROM DE1 AS c
```

I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try an inner join instead:

```
select 
  sum(case when de2.status = 'OnHold'   then 1 else 0 end) as OnHold_Count
, sum(case when de2.status = 'Disabled' then 1 else 0 end) as Disabled_Count
, sum(case when de2.status = 'Enabled'  then 1 else 0 end) as Enabled_Count
from de1 
inner join de2 on de2.email = de1.email
```

Comment: Thank you @adam-spriggs adding inner join seems to be working but i am not getting correct total. I have tried changing sum() to count() and the total count is not correct still. In my case, i am trying to count the total contacts (looks like sum function is only good to calculate numbers). In my production de, i need to add multiple conditions within each case and i am seeing incorrect counts. I am using multiple condition like this `count(distinct case when de2.status = 'OnHold'  and d2.comments <> 'test' then 1 else 0 end) as OnHold_Count`

Comment: I changed the query like this and it seems to be working fine and giving correct count. `count(distinct case when de2.status = 'OnHold' and d2.comments <> 'test' then de2.Email else null end) as OnHold_Count`. this is working fine,  just curious for your thoughts this change?

Comment: There's no way to validate your counts since you haven't provided any details about your data.  I'd stick with sum().

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I did not provide any sample data as I though column names were self explanatory. I am looking here and it says SUM function is used to calculate the sum while in this case I am trying to find total count of records: [https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1005064/Difference-between-sum-and-count-in-sql-quer](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1005064/Difference-between-sum-and-count-in-sql-query)

Comment: The case statement returns a 1 or a 0, so the sum should count the total records for each case.

Comment: Ok so in this can we say count and sum are interchangeable? I am just curious why you prefer sum over count? Is there anything that makes sum function a better choice?

Comment: Maybe, but the answer is in you testing it with the data.  Something like this I'd model in SQL Server Management Studio and then implement in SFMC.